# when I add a datetimepicker in visual studio and add the following part of code for the save button using vb.net, why does it show an error message?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

Error message - ('Incorrect date value: '11/17/2021' for column 'Date_joined' at row1)

```
Dim query As String
conn.Open()
query = "INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`tblmember` (`Name`, `NIC`, `Gender`,`Contact`,`Email`,`Date_Joined`) VALUES ('" & txtname.Text & "', '" & txtNIC.Text & "', '" & txtgender.Text & "','" & txtcontact.Text & "','" & txtemail.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "');"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
RENDER = Command.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: [Date literal in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) may be only `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `YYYYMMDD`. Format the output of the control accordingly or use STR_TO_DATE() function in the query.

Comment: Better even, use parameterized queries instead of string concatenations

Comment: yeah I gave a custom format and set the format to custom..... I got a video in youtube and it says to put datetimepicker1.Text not datetimepicker1.Value.Date...

Comment: Use a parameterized query. What happens when `txtgender.Text = "nonbinary butch furrykin'; DROP TABLE [librarydb].[tblmember];"`?

Comment: What is the datatype of Date_Joined in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Never concatenate strings to build a `CommandText`. **ALWAYS** use parameters. A value inserted in a text box and concatenated into `CommandText` can be executed by the server. (Drop Table) Values of parameters are not considered as executable code by the server.

You wouldn't open the connection until directly before the `Execute...`.

You would use `ExecuteReader` with an Insert command.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim query = "INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`tblmember` (`Name`, `NIC`, `Gender`,`Contact`,`Email`,`Date_Joined`) 
                        VALUES (@Name, @NIC, @Gender, @Contact, @Email, @Date);"
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtname.Text
            .Add("@NIC", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNIC.Text
            .Add("@Gender", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtgender.Text
            .Add("@Contact", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcontact.Text
            .Add("@Email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtemail.Text
            .Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
        End With
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```